# "Array index is out of bounds" on Exceptions's super call in Groovy

Tags: java, exception, groovy, sonarqube, super

I have an `Exception` class: (in groovy)

```
class TestException extends RuntimeException {
    TestException(String msg) {
        super(msg)
    }
}
```

But sonar is showing *Array index is out of bounds* on `super` call

[image: sonar bug message]

I didn't get why I am getting this Bug message here. Does anyone have any idea/clue why this bug being shown?

Comment: @RobOhRob there is no exception. It is a Sonar Warning.

Comment: @MKB does this warning just occur in sonarcloud/sonarqube or does it occur in sonarlint too? Can you show how you analyze it? (CI script or whatever)

Comment: Does this also happen with `@CompileStatic`?

Comment: @dan1st, I have installed sonarlint on my IDE (Intellij Idea), but this plugin does not work on groovy code. And I am using https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.sonarqube plugin for sonar analysis.

Comment: @cfrick, I run the sonarqube with `@CompileStatic`, and now sonar is not reporting this bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These warnings are gone after using `@CompileStatic`.